# matching text in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data frame looks like -

```
id                  text
1           i am interested.
2           don't call me.I am bzy.
3           pls help me regarding this product.
4           donot call me.
5           I have some req.please mail me.
```

My final data frame looks like -

```
id                  text                                 results
1           i am interested.                                yes
2           don't call me.I am bzy.                         no
3           pls help me regarding this product.             yes
4           donot call me.                                  no      
5           I have some req.please mail me.                 yes
```

I have written the following code -

```
d1 = {'no': ['not interested','don't', 'donot']}

# create regex 
reg = '|'.join([f'\\b{x}\\b' for x in list(d1.values())[0]])

# apply function
df['results'] = df['text'].str.lower().str.contains(reg).map({True: 'no', False: 'yes'})
```

getting error -

```
File "<ipython-input-59-62192b95d669>", line 1
    d1 = {'irrelevant': ['not interested','don't','donot']}
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use double quotation: `['not interested',"don't",'donot']`?

Comment: try adding the quote with the escape character as `'don\'t'` or  as `"don't"`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the object  is not a string.

You should use an escape character to print the sequence.

```html
d1 = {'no': ['not interested','don\'t', 'donot']}
```